Nature of isolated singular point $z=0$; $f(z)=(z^2+1)\sin(\frac{1}{z})\cos(\frac{1}{z})$
Given $f(z)=(z^2+1)\sin\Big(\frac{1}{z}\Big)\cos\Big(\frac{1}{z}\Big)$, we have:
$$ord(0,f)=ord\Big(0,\frac{(z^2+1)}{2}\sin\Big(\frac{2}{z}\Big)\Big)=ord\Big(0,\frac{(z^2+1)}{2}(\frac{2}{z}- \frac{(\frac{2}{z})^3}{3!}+ \dots)\Big)= - \infty$$
And $res(0,f)=\frac{2}{2}=1$ by the series expansion above; is this correct? Any alternative paths to be taken?
EDIT:
$res(0,f)=\frac{2}{2}-\frac{8}{2\times3!}=\frac{1}{3}$

Your method is the best, but you missed out the term $\frac {z^{2}} 2 (-\frac 8 {3! z^{3}})$ which also gives  a term in $\frac  1 z$.  The residue is $\frac  1 3$.
